# Clarification on cross apply

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a table containing information that happened for a given day (1 day per row).
for every row, an event may happen multiple times.

```
| Id | Sector_1 | Sector_2 | WastedTime_1 | WastedTime_2 | FixingTime_1 | FixingTime_2 |
|----|----------|----------|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|  1 | A        | B        |           15 |           30 |           30 |           60 |
|  2 | B        | C        |           60 |          120 |          120 |          240 |
```

Note that I show here 2 events maximum, but it can go up to 20, and there are multiple other columns, for example, `DateTime_X`, `EmpName`, etc.

I want to create a query that will "pivot" that data so I can see one row per event instead, even if the IDs are duplicated. Ex.:

```
| Id | Sector | WastedTime | FixingTime |
|----|--------|------------|------------|
|  1 | A      |         15 |         30 |
|  1 | B      |         30 |         60 |
|  2 | B      |         60 |        120 |
|  2 | B      |        120 |        240 |
```

I was trying to do it with a pivot but with no success. During my research, I saw the `CROSS APPLY` command, tried it out and it worked.

```
SELECT      Id,
            StopEvent.*
FROM        #events
CROSS APPLY
(
    VALUES  (Sector_1, WastedTime_1, FixingTime_1),
            (Sector_2, WastedTime_2, FixingTime_2)
)   AS  StopEvent(Sector, WastedTime, FixingTime)
```

My question is **why** does it work ? I read a bit on that command and I still don't understand why it works. Also, is `CROSS APPLY` the way to go for this operation or something else ?

Comment: Paul White has a couple of excellent articles that goes over APPLY in great detail. [Understanding and Using APPLY - Part 1](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/APPLY/69953/) and [Understanding and Using APPLY - Part 2](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/APPLY/69954/)

Comment: I didn't encoutered that, will take a look thanks !

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you could use `UNION`:

```
SELECT Id, Sector_1 AS Sector, WastedTime_1 AS Wasted_Time, FixingTime_1 AS FixingTime FROM #events
UNION ALL
SELECT Id, Sector_2, WastedTime_2, FixingTime_2 FROM #events
ORDER BY Id, Sector;
```

Your current approach using `APPLY` might outperform the union approach.